# Continue function if returned function is not returning

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reduce cyclomatic complexity but this is a general query.
if function **b** is not returning anything function **a** should continue to return 3

```js
function a() {
  return b();
  return 3
}

function b() {
  if (false)
    return 2
}
alert(a())
```

Comment: `if (false)` will never branch.

Comment: @GetSet if(true) is working fine I want to deal with the situation where if its false then function a should continue to return 3

Answer (score 3):

More manually you could store the result of `b()` in a variable, check the variable, and conditionally `return` or continue.  Though in this simplified version you could also just rely on the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) when returning.

For example:

```js
function a() {
  return b() ?? 3;
}

function b() {
  if (false)
    return 2
}
alert(a())
```

Essentially the expression resolves to either the result of `b()` or, if that result is `null` or `undefined`, resolves to `3`.  Then the result of that overall expression is returned.

Comment: Additionally, I would add that it is impossible to know that the function truly returned something since you can technically return `undefined`. Would it be good programming? Probably not, but you can...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: True, `undefined` or `null` can be *explicitly* returned.  And if the OP needs to discern between the two then a more direct comparison on the result is required.  I struggle to imagine a meaningful difference between explicitly calling `return undefined;` and just not having a `return` statement though.  At this point we're mostly just thinking aloud.

Answer (score 0):

That works with my test, "I used `console.log` not `alert`"

```js
function a() {
  let val = b()
  return val == null ? 3 : val;
}

function b() {
  if (false) return 2;
  return null; // If anytings doesnt return that function we returns null 
}
alert(a());
```

Performance test for nullish operator or standart one line if
https://jsbench.me/ool12lcckh